# Automatic "Script database as... create" for SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'd like to make a daily automatic creation of the creation script for a database in SQL Server 2008, meaning having a (bat, exe, ... whatever) that creates a text file with the very same output obtained by right-clicking on the database in SQL Management Studio and do Script database as... --> Create to... --> New Query window.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance,

Mauro

EDIT 1: We already used SMO but a couple of things are annoying

- Needs compatibility pack in SQL Server 2008 (confirm?)
- Some things were not created in script (some indexes and keys and in table creation schema is lost)

Best choice for me would something with a powershell script but any other idea is welcome!

Comment: There are probably a couple of third party tools out there that does exactly what you want. I use one of them and is a very happy user. Is it an option to buy something?

Comment: Hi Mikael, yes it is an option depending on price. Could you please share the tool you are using? Thx

Comment: I use AdaptSQL Diff http://www.adeptsql.com/. There is is COM interface you can use if you want to automate the generation of SQL scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SMO. For example: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated (see the Scripting Objects section).

More info on SMO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx